# Static Webpage hosted in a EC2 instance

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I followed cloud guru's course to create a ec2 instance in aws. I installed apache webserver and created a static page. When I login to the ec2 instance and run the curl command (from within ec2 instance) using "Public DNS (IPv4)" address , I am able to view the page in browser. However when I try to open it in my browser, I am unable to view. I did not make any changes to outbound rules in my security group.

I am unable to access the page using the public ipv4 ipaddress both from within ec2 and outside.

Comment: if you're not able to hit the public IP from within the ec2, I'd check your apache config, maybe it is only listening to localhost?

Comment: Thanks will check , I am able to hit the private ip from within ec2 though

Comment: Should I change the config to Listen <public ip v4 address>:80?

Comment: That didn’t seem to work :( wasn’t able to bind to that when I restarted Apache

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment due to new user. This seems "security group" inbound rule issues. Did you open port 80 in security group "inbound"?

When you use "public IP" even from EC2 box, that will be considered as traffic from internet and if your security group is not configured to accept (inbound) traffic from internet, you can't access the website available on port.

NOTE: Suggest to open port to "MyIP" instead of "whole world".

Comment: Great! Good luck! Be careful with security group inbound, don't open it to everyone unless needed. Bad actors could hack your box.

Comment: Thank you! I did that for testing it. I changed it to my ip address as you recommended :)